# How to sort an arraylist into increasing order without using any existing sort methods in java?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I need to sort an array of incoming integer values into increasing order, but I can't use any existing sort methods (so no Collections.sort(array)).

```
public void insert(Integer value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        array.add(value);
    }
}
```

Here is my probably over complicated and failed attempt.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    array.add(value);
}

if(array.size() >= 2) {
    value2 = array.get(0);
    for(int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {
        if(j != 0) {
            if(value2 < array.get(j)) {
                array.set(0, array.get(j));
                array.set(j, value);
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are tons of sorting algorithms from which to choose from.

Comment: what sort algorithm trying to implemenent?

Comment: If you don't want to google for it, then at least write the logic out on a piece of paper first.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for an *insertion sort*? Is that what `insert` is meant to do? If so, why aren't you calling it?

Comment: Instead of using if (j !=0), you may just want to start indexing into the array at element 1 with for (int j = 1; j<array.size(); j++).

Comment: Try implementing selection sort. Find the lowest value and sort it in the first index. Then find the second highest value and put it in the second index, and so on.

Comment: What is `insert` method, why are iterating for `size()` times? By the way you can do something like: `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(new TreeSet<Integer>(unsortedList));` cause `TreeSet` is an `SortedSet`.

Answer (score 1):

As people in the comments have said, there are multiple sorting algorithms.

Here is one of the simplest algorithms that I used in my college (but this use string array):

You can modify it to use a list.

```
String temp = "";
for(int i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
    {
        if(array[i].compareTo(array[j]) > 0)
        {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a shellsort, which is not the fastest or best sorting algorithm, but will get the job done on a small list.

```
public void sort(Integer[] values)
{
    for (int gap = values.length / 2; gap > 0; 
            gap = gap == 2 ? 1 : (int) (gap / 2.2) )            
        {
            for (int i = gap; i < values.length; i++)
            {
                Integer tmp = values[i];
                int j = i;

                for (; j >= gap && tmp.compareTo(values[j-gap]) < 0; j -= gap)
                {
                    a[j] = a[j - gap];
                }
                a[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). It's one of the easiest sorting algorithms (slower than insertion, but faster than bubble). It compares each element in the list to the rest of the elements in the list. The list will progressively be sorted from the beginning to the end (starting with `i = 0`).

`i` is comparing to all of the other elements in the list, `j`, and when that value at the `i` index is found to be greater than the value at the `j` index, the values are swapped and the comparisons continue.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> selectionSort(ArrayList<Integer> array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.size(); j++)
        {
            if (array.get(i) > array.get(j)) {

                int temp = array.get(j);
                array.set(j, array.get(i));
                array.set(i, temp);
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

---

I'll test it here:

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(2);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(19);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(1);

    list = selectionSort(list);

    for (int i : list) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
4
5
7
19
```